# Forking in Django

Tags: python, django, linux

I am trying to make `os.fork()` in django view and get an error: `Port 8000 already in use`. As I understand when I do `os.fork()` file descriptors inherits and I get two sockets in the same port in two processes.

```
   def view(request):
       ...
       if not os.fork():
          target()
       return

    def target(*args, **kwargs):
       ...
       sd = socket.socket(*args, **kwargs)
       sd.bind(*args)
       sd.listen()
       nsd = sd.accept()
      ...
```

If I do `os.close()` in child for opened descriptors, I get WSGI-error:

```
for i in os.listdir("/proc/%s/fd" % os.getpid()):
   os.close(int(i))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 94, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 135, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 218, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 197, in send_preamble
    self._write('HTTP/%s %s\r\n' % (self.http_version,self.status))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 404, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I need to this exaclty as separate process and I do not want use 3-d party apps such as celery.

Comment: *Why* (in heavens name), are you trying to fork your Django process after it has bound to ports already? Generally speaking the answer is: *Don't do that*.

Comment: for more background: you are setting up two identical django processes. The new one won't be able to access the ports (as you have noticed). `close()`ing the ports won't help - the new django process wants to continue doing exactly what the old one did - including accessing the ports - hence the WSGI error - calling `close()` doesn't solve anything. It's really unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you were writing C I'd suggest you call `exec()` - however since this is Python you can probably do something more high level - will the `subprocess` module help you achieve what you want?

Comment: I believe if you are trying to fork() a django view maybe you are looking to your problem in a wrong way. Can you please explain what problem are you trying to solve by forking the process?

Comment: From the code, it's trying to bind in the child process ( in target()) which would fail if the parent is already bound or if two child processes try to do this. Normally you fork() after accept(), and the child then closes the listen socket, the parent closes the accepted socket; but yes this this seems to be a structural issue, the whole point of using something like django is that it takes care of these details for you.

Comment: OK. Finally I want to run an outer program as daemon with specific configuration file, using data from form. Also with this program in separate process I Want to start socket server, that will process output from first program.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is very simple. Since Python does not scale to multiple cores you have to fork it. GENERALLY SPEAKING: THIS IS NORMAL THING TO DO! Don't advice something completely false.

Comment: @freakish: You misunderstand me; you need to fork *before* binding to ports. Leave forking up to a dedicated WSGI server instead.

Comment: @freakish: I never said it was impossible; I said it's not a good idea; the problem has already been solved in a scalable and practical way and packaged up for you as WSGI server, which work great with Django.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, sorry, I guess you're right. I misunderstood you and the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right solution would be to use celery (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) or the equivalent.

Comment: As I have written before I don not want to use third-party-apps